# Simple VBA excel select specific part from text files

Tags: vba, excel

My text file contains something like

a , b , c , d

I want to select only b and c

So far I already make macro that can read all data (a,b,c,d)

```
    With ws.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & File, ws.Cells(1, 1))
    .FieldNames = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = columnFormats
    .Refresh
    End With
```

What I need to add for selecting b and c only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 1, 1, 9)
```

where 9 stands for skip

Comment: Works! But 2nd column format not number, how can I change the format to number with 0 decimal? (ex 121395715917519)

Comment: You can use the following constants to specify the column data types during the data import: xlGeneralFormat, xlTextFormat, xlSkipColumn, xlDMYFormat, xlDYMFormat, xlEMDFormat, xlMDYFormat, xlMYDFormat, xlYDMFormat, xlYMDFormat. Where the last 7 options are date formats. So, there are no number formats available during the text import. Maybe you could do the number formatting after the import?

Comment: Or you don't want it to be formatted as a number? Use for the second column _xlTextFormat_

Comment: Actually I need number format because I got long number like 130916001000009 > become 130916E+14 something like this but I will try to format it after import, thanks!